# How can I append the page number in the request endpoint

Tags: python, django, pagination, postman

I am having a URL as below:

HTTP Request Method : `GET`

Endpoint: `http://localhost:8000/api/<client_id>/getshowscount`

I am using a paginator class in my Django code.

```
class ShowListPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

class ClientShowSongListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (DashboardAccess,)
    serializer_class = ShowCountSerializer
    pagination_class = ShowListPagination

def get_queryset(self):        
    return ShowSong.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)
```

Everything works fine. But, the requirement says that I need to have URL endpoint as below:

Endpoint examples:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/<client_id>/getshowscount/?page=1
http://localhost:8000/api/<client_id>/getshowscount/?page=2
```

By the above endpoint examples, I mean to say that I need to append the page also in the URL depending upon the pages. I checked the paginator class. But I didn't find anything useful. Can anyone suggest some workarounds for the same?

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: @Arakkal Abu The problem here is I want to get the /?page = 1 to be appended in the URL by default. irrespective of the second page exists or not. I need to have page also there

Comment: AFAIK, Django doesn't have that facility. Maybe you could handle it where the API call initiating, probably in front-end

Comment: @ArakkalAbu can I append the page option in next and previous of pagination?